# How to Set the Content Type in a ActionController::TestCase request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I was trying to perform a get in my TestCase like this:

```
request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
get :index,:application_name=>"Heka"
```

Though, it fails with a:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template alarm_events/index with {:handlers=>[:builder, :haml, :erb, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml], :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html]
```

Despite that in my controller I have:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def index
    @alarm_events=[...]

    respond_with @alarm_events do |format|
      format.json{
        render :json=>@alarm_events.map{|e| e.to_portal_representation}.to_json, 
               :content_type=>'application/json'
      }
    end
  end
```

How the hell should I code the intended request on the TestCase?

**When I request alarm_events.json in the browser it works fine.**

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to specify the format in the params for action controller testing:

```
get :index, {format: :json}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution if you provide a default format in your routing table (e.g. `defaults: { format: :json }`). Your `TestCase` requests don't go through the routing table so they won't have that default format attached.

Answer (score 6):

```
@request.accept = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to set the header inside the format.json

```
def index
    @alarm_events=[...]

    respond_with @alarm_events do |format|
      format.json{
        render :json => @alarm_events.map{|e| e.to_portal_representation}.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json'
      }
    end
```